# How to mathematically write a limit of sum of the series starting from a square root of a number between 0 and 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, sums-of-squares

Suppose, we take a number between 0 and 1 which is x.

How can I write a limit of sum of this series:

sqrt(x) + sqrt(sqrt(x)) .. and so on until a square root limits to 1.

Getting a square root from a number between 0 and 1 on a calculator repeatedly gives us 1. Hence, is my question.

Comment: The sum will be infinite, because (for example), after a sufficiently many (but finite) number of terms (i.e. square root applications) each term will be greater than $1/2,$ and so there will be infinitely many terms each of which is greater than $1/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that for any convergent infinite sum $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k = L,$ we must have that

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} a_k\right)\\ & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k  - \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}a_k \\ & = L - L = 0\end{align}$$

So essentially, for an infinite sum to converge, the terms of the sum must converge to zero. Conversely, if the terms do not converge to zero, the sum must diverge. In calculus textbooks this is often called the *$n^{th}$ term test for divergence,* but it also goes by other names, such as the *limit test,* or simply the *divergence test.*

So, looking at our sum in particular, I claim that we have $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty x^{2^{-k}},$ for some real number $x$ with $0 < x < 1.$ If the way I've written out the terms with $k$ isn't clear, the point is that $a_1 = x^{2^{-1}} = x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x},$ and $$a_{k+1} = x^{2^{-k-1}} = x^{2^{-k} \cdot 2^{-1}} = \left(x^{2^{-k}}\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{x^{2^{-k}}} = \sqrt{a_k}$$

so that each term is the square root of the one before it.

So, as stated before, for this sum to converge we would require the limit of the terms to go to zero, but when we compute the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{2^{-n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{2^{-n} \ln(x)} = e^{\ln(x) \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-n}} = e^0 = 1$$

we get $1,$ as you indicated, which is clearly nonzero, meaning that the sum is divergent.

Comment: *the sequence being summed must converge to zero* --- You mean that the terms of the series must converge to zero. It's the terms that are summed, not the series/sequence. And the only relevant sequence is the sequence of partial sums, which in fact DOESN'T converge to zero. Also a better google phrase (and more often used in calculus texts) is "$n$th term divergence test" (or "$n$th term test for divergence") since there are many types of divergence tests.

Comment: Sorry, but what does "the sequence being summed" mean to you if not the terms of the series? I think it's quite clear it doesn't mean the partial sums

Comment: The reason for my pedantry is that from the wording of the OPs question, I wasn't sure whether the question was about the convergence of an infinite series or the convergence of the $n$th term of the infinite series (especially given the last sentence about repeatedly pushing the square root button on a calculator). In fact, the question literally asks how to WRITE the sum, not evaluating the sum (or determining its existence), but I assumed this was an [ESL issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language).

Comment: I guess that's fair actually, I automatically read "limit of sum" and assumed they meant the sum itself. If I'm wrong on that I apologize for jumping to conclusions. (and I'll switch over to the nth term thing like you pointed out - when I was learning it was always just called the limit test so that's the name which gets stuck in my head)

Comment: @StephenDonovan My question was indeed "how to write" and I meant that, but I got more then answer to my question. So, you don't have to apologize, you gave me a perfect food for the mind. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @AndrewAnderson Yeah I'm not sure how I glazed right over that, I just didn't read very carefully I guess - in any case, I'm glad you've found it helpful regardless. With that in mind I realize I didn't really do much to discuss the notation of the sum itself, if it would be helpful for you I'd be happy to talk about that more